# CSS min-height not working on webkit

Tags: ios, css

so for my website http://vea.re I have setup some css to have each section be 100% of the browser screen size. It works very well on the desktop browsers but on iOS it just does not seem to work. Dou you have any idea why? Actually it does not work on webkit/Safari either. Latest chrome has already switched to blink?

The way it is setup is so:

```
body  
   #container
      section
```

The css is the following

```
html, body{
    height: 100%; position: relative;
}
#container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
section{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I am using min-height because sometimes the section is bigger than 100% of the screen.
It works without any problems on the desktop, but not on my iphone or ipad.

I need a css only solution, I had it working what javascript before, but it is rather suboptimal because of loading times and such.

Comment: Can you narrow down the code and put on jsfiddle? Off-topic: pretty website.

Comment: Hey, I started it http://jsfiddle.net/lukasoppermann/pLaur/10/ but i did not get it to work yet, will finish it tomorrow, seems to be a webkit thing though, not ios exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems to be working with `height: 100%` instead if `min-height` and I do not know what I changed but now it does not cut off the sections if they are longer.